# ASP.NET button link overwrites folder extension in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I feel almost stupid asking this because I think the answer is probably very basic. But, here it goes.

I am designing a website with a button that "rolls dice" then enables other buttons on the page (categories in my game), which ultimately, will use those buttons to go to the proper category. So, in effect, [click "roll ..."], the C# of the page (Game.aspx.cs) processes which buttons to enable, display/enable those buttons for click-ability.

My problem is this:

The page is

```
[domain]/UncommonSense/Game.aspx
```

but after I click the "roll ..." button the URL turns to

```
[domain]/Game.aspx#/Game.aspx
```

This causes a problem in the `categories` buttons because I need to redirect to

```
[domain]/UncommonSense/Question.aspx
```

but since `Game.aspx#/` has taken the place of `UncommonSense/` it fails.

CODE:

Okay, here is the code in my Game.aspx file. The button is the "ID=Roll" button listed right below "Label12." The code behind is literally right now a blank function so it is not doing anything on the C# side except posting back (apparently). However, when that button is clicked the URL goes from:

[domain]/UncommonSense/Game.aspx
to
[domain]/Game.aspx#/Game.aspx

NOTE: I just tested from a root directory and it did about the same thing:

[domain]/Game.aspx
became
[domain]/Game.aspx#/Game.aspx

Maybe this has something to do with the form?

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Game.aspx.cs" Inherits="Uncommon_Sense.Game" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Uncommon Sense</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Uncommon Sense"></asp:Label></h1>
    </div>


    <div data-role="content">
        <h4><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Game Statistics"></asp:Label></h4>
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" data-mini="true" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" data-mini="true" Text=""></asp:Label>

        <h4><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Game Play"></asp:Label></h4>
<asp:Button ID="Roll" runat="server" Text="Roll Dice ..." data-mini="true" 
            onclick="Roll_Click" />
        <hr width="80%" />
    <div class="ui-grid-c">

    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <asp:Button ID="btnShortStuffChecked" runat="server" Text="Short Stuff" data-mini="true" 
            data-icon="check" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnShortStuffNotChecked" runat="server" Text="Short Stuff" data-mini="true" 
            Enabled="False" Visible="False" onclick="btnShortStuffNotChecked_Click" /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <asp:Button ID="btnWhoSaidChecked" runat="server" Text="Who Said?" data-mini="true" 
            data-icon="check" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnWhoSaidNotChecked" runat="server" Text="Who Said?" data-mini="true" 
            Enabled="False" Visible="False" /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <asp:Button ID="btnCommonQuipChecked" runat="server" Text="Common Quip" data-mini="true" 
            data-icon="check" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCommonQuipNotChecked" runat="server" Text="Common Quip" data-mini="true" 
            Enabled="False" Visible="False" /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-d">
        <asp:Button ID="btnRhymeTimeChecked" runat="server" Text="Rhyme Time" data-mini="true" 
            data-icon="check" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnRhymeTimeNotChecked" runat="server" Text="Rhyme Time" data-mini="true" 
            Enabled="False" Visible="False" /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAnythingGoesChecked" runat="server" Text="Anything Goes" data-mini="true" 
            data-icon="check" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAnythingGoesNotChecked" runat="server" Text="Anything Goes" data-mini="true" 
            Enabled="False" Visible="False" /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <asp:Button ID="btnDefineItChecked" runat="server" Text="Define It" data-mini="true" 
            data-icon="check" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDefineItNotChecked" runat="server" Text="Define It" data-mini="true" 
            Enabled="False" Visible="False" /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAllAbroadChecked" runat="server" Text="All Abroad" data-mini="true" 
            data-icon="check" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAllAbroadNotChecked" runat="server" Text="All Abroad" data-mini="true" 
            Enabled="False" Visible="False" /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-d">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSpellItChecked" runat="server" Text="Spell It" data-mini="true" 
            data-icon="check" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSpellItNotChecked" runat="server" Text="Spell It" data-mini="true" 
            Enabled="False" Visible="False" /></div>
    </div>
        <h4><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Settings"></asp:Label>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Question.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
        </h4>

    <label for="slider-0">Computer Difficulty:</label>
   <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="2" min="1" max="4"  />
        <h3><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h3>
        <asp:Button ID="ChoiceA" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="ChoiceA_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="False" />


</div>
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

And the answer is ... JQuery Mobile!

By simply removing the reference to JQuery Mobile the problem is solved so apparently this is something in their library that changes URLs. That sucks because I liked using JQuery Mobile. Oh well, my comments will stop now on the annoyance because I am appreciative of the 99.9% of the stuff they do that helps. But, for the record...

ANY LINK will have:

linker.aspx

changed to:

linker#/linker.aspx

for some reason.

Comment: Are you using Server.Transfer("~/UncommonSense/Game.aspx") ? or Response.Redirect ?

Comment: I am actually not using either. Even if I remove all the code from "Roll Button" and just click it on the Game.aspx page the URL changes from: "[domain]/UncommonSense/Game.aspx" to "[domain]/Game.aspx#/Game.aspx"

Comment: If you show us some code... an answer will not be far away.

Comment: Okay, the code has been added. Sorry for not doing it before. I am learning ASP.NET quite a bit still and was embarrassed. :)

Comment: Please remove as much code as possible - show only the relevant parts (e.g. Roll_Click() method of the code-behind file).

Comment: M4N, for starters, THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME!!! This is driving me crazy! In response to your comment though I hate to say that I am so confused about what is happening that I left it all in because of something obvious I may be missing somewhere unrelated to the button. I am not sure that helps though so I will remove anything that is recommended (i.e. - "get ride of all the other webcontrols")